# Who does this pronoun refer to?

Tags: pronouns

Consider this sentence:

> The wise Hanuman reminded Sugreev of the assurance he had given Ram.

I've used the pronoun 'he' to refer to Sugreev here. Is it ambiguous? If so, how should I rewrite the sentence?

Comment: Yes, it is ambiguous. You could write: **The wise Hanuman reminded Sugreev of the assurance the latter had given Ram.**

Comment: Yes,someone might mistake it(He) for hanuman.

Comment: Thanks a lot, guys!

Comment: It's _technically_ ambiguous, but probably not in context, if you go on to talk about what the assurance was.